# (minted) pygtex file contents being output to PDF instead of formatted source code?

Tags: minted, syntax-highlighting, pygments

When I compile my tex doc, instead of getting correctly formatted code, I get what appears to be the contents of the `*.pygtex` files in the `_minted-*` folder. There are no errors with compiling.

I am using TeXLive in VSCode with the LaTeX Workshop extension, and I am on Linux.

The top of my document:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{examplep}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usemintedstyle{default}
```

where my source code is:

```tex
\inputminted[linenos, fontsize=\footnotesize]{Python}{../main.py}
```

Comment: please show a complete small document with the problem

Comment: I've edited the question, hope that is good enough

Comment: sorry but you have posted lots of  unrelated code but nothing anyone can use to see the problem. make a small complete document with just packages needed to show the issue, that includes a minted example that produces bad output

Comment: why `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` do you not use pdflatex?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.